# Topic Retention Time not taking affect

Tags: apache-kafka

My Topic Configs: `min.insync.replicas=2,cleanup.policy=delete,segment.bytes=268435456,retention.ms=172800000,file.delete.delay.ms=60000,max.message.bytes=10485772,delete.retention.ms=86400000,segment.ms=1000`

They are same in broker level except `segment.bytes` which is 1GB not 256mb like in the topic level, and `log.roll.ms` is 1000 on broker level but `log.roll.hours` is 168.

In doc it says `log.roll.ms` is above hours.

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/broker-configs.html#log-roll-hours

PS: On the same cluster, MM2 is working.

I tried to change some parameters and tested that it works but now it doesn't.

Comment: when you say retention time is not working, what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, I couldn't wait enought time... It worked just like before. You can use the upper parameters.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Only closed segments will be deleted. If you have less than your configure bytes (256MB), or segments that have not been rolled (every 1 second is very excessive, btw), then they will remain available. And for any segment that will be deleted, it will be delayed by `file.delete.delay.ms`.